# Return the rows of a DataFrame with index in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of index values and a DataFrame. I want to find all the rows whose index appears in the list. If I do

`data.loc[sample]`

then as long as there is one match from the list I get as many rows returned as elements in sample, and a KeyError otherwise. But most of the rows are full of NaNs because they aren't actually in the dataframe index.

This achieves what I want but seems a little convoluted for what seems like a common enough task.

`data.join( pd.DataFrame(index=sample), how='inner')`

What basic function can do this job?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `df.index.isin(sample)`:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))

>>> df
          0         1         2
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219

sample = [1, 2, 3]
>>> df[df.index.isin(sample)]
          0         1         2
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
```